# Raspberry pi 3 B+ Disk IO Bottleneck

Tags: sd-card, performance, storage, docker

I have a RP3 with several docker containers (11) running at home, some for network purposes, other for IoT. The thing is, I've notice several issues related to disk IO, specially when performing unzip operations (updating containers), other services stop working or response time is way to high. I've been monitoring CPU, RAM utilization and everything seems fine, except for disk IO which is at 100% so I was thinking on adding another sd card to store some containers. Will this improve overall performance? is there a neat way of adding a secondary sd card to my RP3?

I'm using a sandisk ultra hc 1 class 10 16Gb

Comment: why not a USB drive?

Comment: you mean a hard drive? Im afraid it will increase power consumption by too much

Comment: was thinking thumb drive

Comment: I just made a Raid 0 with 2 thumb drives and got 28MB/s read speed, in contrast to the 5MB/s I was getting on the sd card, thats a mayor improvement though

Comment: did you try a single thumb drive first? :p

Comment: Single drive 21MB/s write, 15MB/s read. Raid0 17MB/s write 28MB/s read. Its weird the write speed went down